# Date filter for DataGridView

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I need to make a date filter for DataGridView which gets data by this code

```
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    string query = "select * from Договор";
    string query1 = "select * from Поставщики";

    conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_string);

    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    dataAdapter1.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn);

    dataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Договор");
    dataAdapter1.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Поставщики");

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    dataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet);

    BindingSource dogSource = new BindingSource();
    dogSource.DataSource = dataSet;
    dogSource.DataMember = "Договор";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dogSource;

    BindingSource postSource = new BindingSource();
    postSource.DataSource = dataSet;
    postSource.DataMember = "Поставщики";

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboColumn.HeaderText = "Поставщики";
    comboColumn.DataSource = postSource;

    comboColumn.DataPropertyName = "Код поставщика";

    comboColumn.DisplayMember = "Название";

    comboColumn.ValueMember = "Код поставщика";
```

I used to filter data with this code, but now it did't work, I guess because of DataSource.

```
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format(" CONVERT([Дата заключения], 'System.DateTime') >= '{0:dd.MM.yyyy}' AND CONVERT([Дата заключения], 'System.DateTime') <= '{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'",
    dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());;
    dataGridView1.DataSource=dv;
```

I'll appriciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Dates are not strings so it is not clear why `Дата заключения` has to be converted or why you are converting dates to strings to compare.  There is a fair amount of other overkill as well.  At any rate allow that maybe no data falls into the range passed

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp, yeah, you're right, there's no need for convert, but still it's not working, even headers gone, so that's why I'm sure that problem in DataSource string and I've got no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's right, but it's worked out for me.

```
DataTable all = dataSet.Tables[0];
DataView dv = new DataView(all);
dv.RowFilter = string.Format(" [Дата заключения] >= '{0:dd.MM.yyyy}' AND [Дата заключения] <= '{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
dataGridView1.DataSource=dv;
```